# Splice or Remove list of elements from JSON Array ,removing even numbered items only instead of matching items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

I am having a JSON Array Output from REST API like this , I am displaying this items on the HTML using ng-repeat.

```
    var searchresponse = [{
"items": [{
    "employeeId": "ABC",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "DEF",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "NPK",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

}, {
    "employeeId": "PKN",
    "type": "A",
    "alive": "Yes"
}],
"more": false
}];
```

when user tries to delete using selectall/single select i am calling a REST API to remove the employee id from the db . once i get a successful response i am planning to splice / remove the values that have been selected by the user from the VIEW. I would like to remove the following employeeid and their type,alive removed from the searchresponse

```
    var data1=["ABC","NPK","PKN"];
```

I tried it doing like this

```
var data1=["ABC","NPK"];
var items=searchresponse[0].items;
for(i in items){
if(data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId)!=-1){
    items.splice(i,1);
}
}
console.log(searchresponse[0].items);
```

What happens really is, it removed even numbered items only eg :it removed ABC,PKN . (It is removing 0th ,2nd,4th items in the list . Leaving 1st,3rd items etc).What am i missing here

Comment: It isnt removing  the items from the list

Comment: you can $index to get the index of the object then splice the object from the array

Comment: How can i do it axcl , can you please guide me . I am struck with this thing for a day now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you remove the item from array, the index of other items in the array shift to the left.

Assume you have 4 items in the array(`[a, b, c, d]`) and you are removing the first item so `i=0` then the resulted array in the second iteration will be `[b,c,d]` and `i` will be `i=1` now effectively you have missed `b` in the loop

```js
var searchresponse = [{
  "items": [{
    "employeeId": "ABC",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

  }, {
    "employeeId": "DEF",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

  }, {
    "employeeId": "NPK",
    "type": "D",
    "alive": "Yes"

  }, {
    "employeeId": "PKN",
    "type": "A",
    "alive": "Yes"
  }],
  "more": false
}];

var data1 = ["ABC", "NPK", "PKN"];

var data1 = ["ABC", "NPK"];
var items = searchresponse[0].items;
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId) != -1) {
    items.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(searchresponse[0].items);
```

Comment: Wowww !! Thank you So much Johny . It worked like a Charm !! Thanks for the Explanation too :)